# Cannot import mongodb fields in flask-mongorest application

Tags: python, mongodb, flask

Thanks in advance for any help.

I've installed all my dependencies using pip in a virtualenv... lets get that out of the way first.
My issue is near the bottom, db.StringField() does not resolve. I'm using pycharm -- I have dug out the file that supposedly contains the field definitions:

```
$PROJ_DIR/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mongoengine/base/fields.py
```

---

But I don't know how to import this file either. And I'm worried that using that class may interfere with MongoRest, but I have no idea.

---

```
from flask import Flask, request, redirect
import twilio.twiml
from flask.ext.mongorest import MongoRest
from flask.ext.mongorest.views import ResourceView
from flask.ext.mongorest.resources import Resource
from flask.ext.mongorest import operators as ops
from flask.ext.mongorest import methods
from flask.ext.mongoengine import MongoEngine


app = Flask(__name__)

app.config.update(
    MONGODB_HOST = 'localhost',
    MONGODB_PORT = '27017',
    MONGODB_DB = 'SMSYOGADEX',
)

db = MongoEngine(app)
api = MongoRest(app)

class Sms(db.Document):
    smsId = db.StringField()
```

---

I've been working on [this tutorial](https://github.com/elasticsales/flask-mongorest) in github.

Thanks again for any help.
Blake--

Answer (score 0):

Well, I found this:

```
from mongoengine.fields import StringField
```

Hopefully that will work out, but I'm not 100% this is the proper way to do things.